# Efficiently design chained promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, async.js

There is an external API that returns 20 objects per call. The response also contains the next page URL (another 20) if there are more objects.

I had explored [async parallelLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#parallelLimit) but it is unsuitable for the above scenario when the next execution depends on the previous execution.

The only solution I came up with using `do...while` loop but, it is extremely slow as the page size could be 2000 (2k pages * 20 records per page = 40k). Unfortunately, it takes somewhere between 7-20 minutes to fetch the records. I am storing these records in cache but after expiry, the same amount of time takes to refresh the cache.

Therefore seeking a bit of advice on how this can be optimised.
Is there an async approach?

```js
const getAllRecords = async (baseUrl, oauthToken) =>. {

    let records = [];
    let pageCount = 0;
    let response;
    let success = false;

    do {
            
        // which page
        pageCount = pageCount + 1;

        // axios request for 20 records
        response = await axios.get(baseUrl + RESOURCE_ENDPOINT,
                { 
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oauthToken
                    },
                    params: {
                        page: pageCount,
                        page_length: 20
                    }
                }
        );

        success = (response.status === 200);

        if (success) {
            records = records.concat(response.data.data);
        }

        console.log('page=' + pageCount + ' | totalRecords=' + records.length);
        console.log(response.data.pagination.next_page); // next page

    } while (success && response.data.pagination.next_page);

    return records;
}
```

Comment: If the bottleneck is network speed, why not increase the page_length parameter you're sending?

Comment: Unfortunately, the max limit for `page_length` is 20 for this endpoint. There is no issue with network speed. If the pages are under 5 then it takes around 2-8 seconds to get 100 records. The response may contain an entire HTML document(s) in one or more records in the payload.

Comment: What is the size of the data? The reason i'm asking is that if you keep 40k records in an array `records` and each record might have entire HTML document in them then it's a huge amount of data. Try to run the code but ignore the response, don't store it anywhere, just to see how long it takes to fetch all of the records. If that is reasonably quick then the problem might be the way you store the data. Maybe it would be better to store it in some files instead of keeping it all in the memory.

Comment: I have tested for a large data (40k) where I had to wait for 8+ minutes. Finally stopped loop forcefully, so it didn’t reach to point where it stores into cache.
But yeah I can try without concat.

Comment: If every request is dependent on its prior then by design you can't use async functionality, am I mistaken?

Comment: Hi @Molda, I tried executing without storing any data in memory/cache. It improved execution time by 500 milliseconds per 2 seconds.

Comment: @Yoel Nisanov, you are right. Trying my luck if anyone able to solve this differently. I am thinking to execute batches of 20 tasks in parallel until one of the tasks fails and stop spawning tasks.